# Microsoft PowerBI: Failed to load the security library: krb5_64.dll

Tags: kerberos, cloudera, impala, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to connect from PowerBi to Impala with Kerberos using ODBC.

I followed by this https://plenium.wordpress.com/2019/08/02/connect-microsoft-power-bi-desktop-to-cloudera-impala-with-kerberos/

I can create ODBC connection with valid credentials and execute query form other tools (for example ODBC Query Tool), but from PowerBi I have this error with loading Kerberos dll:

```
Details: "ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Cloudera][Support] (50366) Failed to load the security library: krb5_64.dll
ERROR [HY000] [Cloudera][Support] (50366) Failed to load the security library: krb5_64.dll"
```

Have you any suggestions about how to resolve it?

I have:

- Windows 10 Pro version 1903
- MIT Kerberos for Windows 4.1
- Cloudera ODBC Driver for Impala 2.6.8 (C6 Compatible)
- Microsoft Power BI Desktop 2.78.5740.721 64-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is: don't install PowerBI as windows app, instead directly download
PBIDesktopSetup_x64.exe and install it. Now its destination is C:\ProgramFiles\"Microsoft Power BI Desktop" not C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsApps\ ...  and it works.